# Validate whether LinkedList<Integer> values are in Ascending and descending or not?

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I have a test case for sorting to automate. There is a column called Primary Phone, which is having the values like below(fetched from web table column i.e. web table is already sorted. Need to fetch and test whether values are in Ascending or descending order)

```
+1 0107968641x551, 
+1 (814) 775-5474, 
+1 (308) 729-2823, 
+1 5258739916x978, 
390655889900, 
+1 (100) 100-1001 x000, 
+1 (111)22222,
```

I am trying to fetch(this is returing String and i am trying to convert from String to Integer using valueOf and parseInt) the values and trying to save it to LinkedList but it is throwing NumberFormatException.

Note: If I use LinkedList, compareTo method is returning the wrong comparison. 
 Any best way to Save the fetched values and compare that, values are in Ascending or Descending order?

Code used:

```
LinkedList<Integer> records = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(Integer row=0; row< numberOfVisibleRows; row++) {

            String value = table.getCellValue(row, columnNumber).trim();
            System.out.println("-->>" + value);
            Integer recordValue =Integer.valueOf(value);
            if(recordValue != null) {
                records.add(recordValue);
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: It appears that you have more than one question. However, neither question is well-defined.

Comment: You cannot use `Integer.valueOf(value)` out-of-box because your values contain spaces, hyphens, brackets and so on. You may need to remove all that stuff first.

Comment: @PatrickParker basically I have a table and all columns are already sorted. The table has multiple columns with different data types like a number, string, and numeric string. Now my task is to fetch those values from the table and check those are in ascending order or not. The difficulty is that string has special characters, Korean languages and the phone number is mixed with + - () like +1 (100) 100-1001 x000.  Is there any way to test these?

Comment: your phone column is most likely sorted using lexicographic order so just use String

Comment: " Is there any way to test these? " Yes, there are multiple ways. That's the problem. You lack specificity.